# Error: 'template<class T> class Two' used without template parameters

Tags: c++

Hey so I'm trying to compile:

```
//ASSIGNMENT
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Two { 

    private: T x,y;
    public: 

        Two (T a, T b); 
        friend void Show (Two p);
        ~Two();

};
//ASSIGNMENT


template <class T>
Two::Two (T a, T b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

friend void Two::Show(Two p){
    cout << p.x << " and " << p.y << endl;
}

int main () {
    Two<int> class2(2,3);
    Show(class2);
}
```

The assignment was to define the members of the class (in the //ASSIGNMENT tags). I don't know why it won't compile... Thanks!

Comment: `friend` functions aren't member functions. If they were member functions, they wouldn't need to be `friend` functions since they could already access the class's private stuff.

Comment: Your destructor is not defined btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
template <class T>
Two::Two (T a, T b)
```

to

```
template <class T>
Two<T>::Two (T a, T b)
```

and make the analogous change wherever it's needed.

Comment: So I did, [this](http://ideone.com/NocjGY) happened. So there is **no** way to define a friend function outside of a class?

Comment: @MK3GTX - as others have told you, this `friend` function is **not** a member function. Don't define it as one.

Comment: @MK3GTX: As chris suggested in the comments, a friend function is *not* a member function. It is a regular free function which is granted the rights to access non-public members of the class(es) it is friend of

Comment: Understood. The directions on this assignment explicitly define it as such. Thank you.